# Find multiple lines with |find in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find

I'm trying to make a batch file to run the `systeminfo` command in Windows 7, and narrow down the results to not show the Hot Fix Information - or just some specific lines.

Is there a way to do this without writing out the command multiple times?
I.e., right now, I have the following:

```
systeminfo|find "System Boot Time"

systeminfo|find "Host Name"

systeminfo|find "OS Name"
```

etc.

The problem with this is it has to reload all the information from the systeminfo cmd for each new line, making it take fairly long. Is it possible to just run the command once and have |find pull up multiple lines?

If not, is it possible to *remove* information with another command? (I haven't heard of anything like this but not sure it doesn't exist)

Comment: You can also create a file from the output of a single systeminfo command, and search it many times with find or findstr.  Endoro's solution is great for those three items but you may want to parse the lines further in different ways for each one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
systeminfo|findstr /c:"System Boot Time" /c:"Host Name" /c:"OS Name"
```

For more information about `findstr` please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844868/what-are-the-undocumented-features-and-limitations-of-the-windows-findstr-comman/8844873#8844873).

Comment: Thanks for this `or` search. You can even add `/i` to make the search case-insensitive.

Comment: this is ok for `or` search but how can we do `AND` search??

Comment: for AND Try to call findstr & findstr and check errorlevel after. Better to save sysinfo to a file before and run findstr & findstr on that file. Remove the file after.